# WordPress + Facebook comments addition (php knowledge needed)

Tags: php, html, facebook, wordpress

I succeded to fetch Facebok comments number via this function:

```
<?php 
function fb_comment_count() { 
global $post; 
$url = get_permalink($post->ID); 

$filecontent = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/?ids=' . $url); 
$json = json_decode($filecontent); 
$count = $json->$url->comments; 
if ($count == 0 || !isset($count)) { 
    $count = 0; 
} 
echo $count; 
} 
;?>
```

And I call it with:

```
<?php fb_comment_count();?>
```

Now how do I add it to this code:

```
<?php comments_number(__('No Comments'), __('1 Comment'), __('% Comments'), '', __('Comments Closed') ); ?>
```

so that WordPress shows number of WP and FB comments together in one number.

Thank you very much to everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the last line of your fb_comment_count function to `return $count;`. That way you'll have a number to deal with.

Now inside the loop, add this:

```
<?php 
$fb_comments = fb_comment_count();
$wp_comments = get_comments_number();
$total_comments = $fb_comments + $wp_comments;
printf ("<p>There are %d Total Comments: %d Wordpress Comments + %d Facebook Comments</p>\n",
        $total_comments, $wp_comments, $fb_comments );
 ?>
```

Comment: Wow, you are great, that works like a charm, you just forgot $ in front of fb_comments

Comment: Thank you very much for this, I am in debt :)

Answer (score 0):

you can also get comments on your post/page with this snippet

```
<fb:comments-count href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"></fb:comments-count></div>
```